# grails related to dropdown

Tags: grails

here is my question :--

```
class ReasonForCancellation {
    String reason
    Status status
    Date lastUpdated
    Date dateCreated

    static constraints = {
    reason(blank:false,maxSize:100,unique:true)
    dateCreated()
    lastUpdated()
    }

    enum Status{
        ACTIVE(true),
        INACTIVE(false)

        private boolean bool

        public Status(boolean bool){
            this.bool = bool
        }
    }

}
```

I have 1 textbox and 1 dropdown in my view page.When i give value "FOO" in textbox and click on active option and save it.It saved .What I need to do that when I click on edit option and click on deactive option and try to give same value "FOO" in text box and save it then it should be updated with the same unique value itself.It should not give alert message of unique.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting the unique constraint because Grails thinks you are trying to save a new record.  You're save method to do an update should look something like:

```
def update = {
  def reasonForCancellation = ReasonForCancellation.get(params.id)
  reasonForCancellation.properties = params
  reasonForCancellation.save()
}
```

And you should have the ID of the editing record in your GSP as a hidden field.  This is pretty standard stuff.  You might want to take some time to read the docs more and / or pick up a good book on Grails.

Comment: do you have any other possible solution because if I see in controller then I can find the same def update= {----} what u wrote above. I'vl be very thankful to you if you go through my question again and answer me. Thanx in advance